# How do Azure Function Apps handle Client Certificate Auth?

Tags: ssl, azure-functions, client-certificates, azure-function-app, mutual-authentication

Hopefully I can make this clear enough.

**Goal:**

- Client Certificate-Authenticated Azure Function

**Scenario:**

- Azure Function **App** with:

  - `HTTPS Only:` set to `Yes`
  - `Client certificate mode:` set to `Require`
- HTTP-triggered Azure Function (Python) which:

  - Loads client certificate [from `X-ARR-ClientCert` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate)
  - Pulls a pre-shared client cert from a database and compares:

    - Issuer
    - CommonName
    - Not Valid Before/After
  - Hits the listed OCSP endpoint to see if cert is revoked
- If properties from each cert match and the certificate has not been revoked, the Function will generate a SAS token for the requestor and send it in the response.

**Question:**

- How is the *cryptographic* part of client cert auth handled in this scenario?
- According to [this (great) blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/ba-p/324623), there is a `CertificateVerify` step where...

`"The client is authenticated by using its private key to sign a`
`hash of all the messages up to this point. The recipient verifies`
`the signature using the public key of the signer, thus ensuring it`
`was signed with the client’s private key."`

I don't see a way to access ...`all the messages up to this point.` to validate this has occured using the Function (Python) code.

Is this something Microsoft handles automagically (similar to how they forward client certs via the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header)? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

From what I implemented in a similar case:

- Your app received the certificate via the header and must:

  - load the certificate (using the library cryptography in python for example)
  - verify the signature of the certificate with you certificate authority
  - verify the date of validity
  - verify that it has not been revoked
- Using web app (but the same would apply to functions), the Azure frontend seems to just launch authentication protocol to verify that the client that send the certificate has the private key associated (and launch the mutual auth protocol as described in the blog post). But it does not verify the validity or signature of the certificate.

The CertificateVerify step you're mentionning seems to be handled by the Azure Frontend, I don't think your need to worry about this process.

Hopes this helps !

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if Azure mentioned this in their documentation

Comment: I would like to know more about the frontend steps Microsoft is taking on behalf of any HTTP-triggered Azure Function. For example, what happens if someone tries a Self-signed cert? Will the Frontend forward this to the Function?

Comment: How can the cert verification be handled by Azure by itself? Afaik, any valid cert with the client authentication purpose (even self-signed) will be accepted. What I am missing is is the ability to specify a trusted CA for this verification purpose.